# nav bar not displaying particular user username and avatar after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies

I am building website in that after login done in my navbar I need to display username and profile pic in the particular user. i set already cookies the usersID and token for the navbar page and routes working in postman correctly getting username and avatar. But in frontend only displaying the span loading in that place after login. how to i get the username and avatar to display.In console not showing userData

console after login

```
    Login Response: {token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0O…IxMH0.iz2R-KRpWm98IkJUkoTBiviIB2HdyMV5trkZALMdY5Q', userID: '64873ecdf5e306a1119fe9ca'}
token
: 
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY0ODczZWNkZjVlMzA2YTExMTlmZTljYSIsImlhdCI6MTY4NzAwMDIxMH0.iz2R-KRpWm98IkJUkoTBiviIB2HdyMV5trkZALMdY5Q"
userID
    : 
"64873ecdf5e306a1119fe9ca"
```

this is my userroutes

```
router.get("/profile/:userID", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userID } = req.params;
    console.log("User ID:", userID); // Log the userID
    const user = await UserModel.findById(userID);
    
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
    }

    // Return the username and profile picture/avatar in the response
    const { username, profilepic } = user;
    
    // Check if the user has a profile picture
    const avatar = profilepic ? profilepic : 'default-avatar.png';
    
    res.json({ username, avatar });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});
```

this is my navbar

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { MDBBtn } from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";


export const Navbar = () => {
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(["access_token"]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [cookiesData] = useCookies(["userID"]);
  const userID = useMemo(() => cookiesData?.userID, [cookiesData]);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/auth/profile/${userID}`);
        const userData = response.data;
        setUserData(userData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    if (userID) {
      fetchUserData();
    }
  }, [userID]);

  const logout = () => {
    removeCookie("access_token");
    removeCookie("userID");
    navigate("/login");
  };

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="logo">
        <Link to="/" className="home">
          <img src="Rephavjp.jpg" alt="Logo" />
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="title">
        <Link to="/createrecipe" className="recipes">
          Recipes
        </Link>
        <Link to="/moments" className="moments">
          Moments
        </Link>
        <Link to="/saved" className="saved">
          Saved
        </Link>
        <Link to="/blog" className="blog">
          Blog
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="login">
        {!cookies.access_token ? (
          <Link to="/auth">
            <MDBBtn rounded className="mx-2" color="info">
              Sign up
            </MDBBtn>
          </Link>
        ) : userData !== null ? (
          <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="info" id="dropdown-basic">
              {userData.username}
              {userData.avatar && (
                <img src={userData.avatar} alt="Profile Avatar" className="avatar" />
              )}
            </Dropdown.Toggle>

            <Dropdown.Menu>
              <Dropdown.Item className="porfilebox" href="#">
                Action
              </Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item className="porfilebox" href="#">
                Another action
              </Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item className="porfilebox" href="#" onClick={logout}>
                Logout
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
        ) : (
          <span>Loading...</span>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**change :**

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
```

**to :**

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
```